# Group lasso and feature selection

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, lasso

I have a dataset with a lot of categorical variables and a binary target variable and I want to put it to an svm.
I converted the categorical variables to dummy variables and since my observations are a lot less than the variables I want to perform feature selection. Since I have categorical variables converted to dummy variables I understand that I cant use simple lasso since it will drop part of the dummy variables.

I'm searching to find a package to implement group lasso on python with a binary target but I cant find any.

I found Adaptive Sparse Group Lasso (asgl) but as far as I understand it doesn't support binary target variables.

I also found group lasso which does sparse group lasso and supports logistic regression. As far as I understand sparse lasso does a combination between group lasso and lasso. I tried using it with parameters values to group_reg=0, or  l1_reg=0 hopping that it would just do group lasso but it keeps droping part of the dummy variables in both cases.

My question is. How do you do group lasso with a binary target variable in python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: isn't l1_reg keeps features and assigns low weight. While l2_reg keeps only prominent features and assigns 0 or very less  weight to others

Comment: if that does not work , try decision tree with pruning .. It is good at classification with large features.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I have 142 observations and 1000+ variables. I think I need to do variable selection.
I think I managed to make it work. I put all variables on a group. Either alone for those that dont belong to a group or with others that belong to the same group. I put l1_reg = 0 and i use group_reg!=0.

Comment: But I still feel I do something wrong. I get accuracy 1.

Comment: How do you have more categories than observations?

Comment: @Dave, the post says after dummifying there are more _features_ than observations, but those will have come from multiple categorical columns and maybe some continuous ones.

Comment: @user342821 you might self-answer with the group-lasso package and parameter settings, and ask a new question about perfect accuracy with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, you need a sparse group logistic regression model to perform feature selection while considering the binary response.

[`skglm`](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/skglm) is a new modular, scikit-learn conform, python package that provides implementations of sparse generalized linear models. You can make a feature request, on its GitHub repository, through [the issue section](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/skglm/issues/new). The team will reach out to you asap. Thanks to the modularity of the package, it's a matter of a few hours to implement your desired model.

Meanwhile, you can use [`celer`](https://github.com/mathurinm/celer). It offers an efficient implementation of [Group Lasso](https://mathurinm.github.io/celer/generated/celer.GroupLasso.html#celer.GroupLasso) that aligns with the `scikit-learn` API. Here is also a [helpful medium article](https://towardsdatascience.com/beyond-linear-regression-467a7fc3bafb) on celer group Lasso and how it can be used to perform feature selection of continuous and categorical variables.

Answer (score -1):

Lasso regularization is a type of cost function regularization that only works with certain types of machine learning algorithms. For example, lasso regularization does not work with support vector machines (SVMs).

A more common way to frame your problem is feature selection for categorical features in binary classification. A couple of techniques are the chi-squared statistic and the mutual information statistic.